# How to get server side error rate metrics for Google cloud spanner and Cloud Bigtable with cloud monitoring or any other way

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to get server error rate for various requests on Cloud bigtable and Cloud Spanner with cloud monitoring api, however in cloud monitoring I see only these available metrics -
for bigtable - https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-bigtable
for spanner - https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-spanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to monitor your instances will be use [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring?hl=en) this could help you to get the metrics that you want.

For example for the server error rates of Cloud Spanner table you can go to the section of `Metrics explorer` and try to create your metric, in the section that says:

```
Resource type
```

you put

```
Cloud Spanner Instance
```

In the section

```
Metric
```

you should put

```
API request rate
```

and add a filter that is the fields

```
label
Comparison
Value
```

you should put the following order:

```
status
!= (does not equal)
ok
```

and for Cloud Bigtable you need to put in

```
Resource type
```

you put

```
Cloud Bistable table
```

In the section

```
Metric
```

you should put

```
Error Count
```

That should give you a metric of the error of the instances that you have